# Mocha First unit test always slower than the others

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

For some reason the first unit test of my test suit is always slower than the others. When executing the tests in my console I get something like:

```
√ unit test A (483ms)
√ unit test B
```

But in the code if I change the unit test B to above the unit test A, I get this:

```
√ unit test B (470ms)
√ unit test A
```

For some reason the first unit tests gets always slower and because of that I think, the reason of being slow in not my code, but something in Mocha. At the same time I have others tests suits that are testing other code and it works fine, so I'm confused. Maybe is not Mocha, but due to not being sure, I need to ask if you have an idea of what can be happening.

The test is something like this:

```
let target = require('...');

describe('Module of unit tests', function () {
  this.timeout(1000);
  before(function () {
        ...
    target = proxyquire('...', {
      'node-chartist': sinon.stub().resolves('...'),
      'ws': function(){
        return {
          'close': function(){ /*Do nothing*/ },
          'send': function(){ /*Do nothing*/ },
          'on': function(arg, callback){
            ...
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });

  //Warning happens here
  it('unit test A', function () {
    ...
    target();
    ...
  });

  //If this unit test goes above unit test A, this will be the one to get 
  the warning.
  it('unit test B', function () {
    ...
    target();
    ...
  });
})
```

`

I tried to reproduce in other projects without success, so I doubt you will be able to do it, but what I'm doing is execute tests suit with unit test A above and then execute tests suit with unit test B above.

Versions:

```
node v6.11.4
npm 3.10.10
mocha 4.0.1
sinon 4.1.2
chai 3.5.0
proxyquire 1.8.0
```

I used fiddler to make sure that while executing the unit tests, none network request was being made for the outside, to make sure that the delay is not caused by any network request.

I also debugged the code that the unit test is testing and I really don't see any reason for the delay in any case.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening because I was making some stubs with proxyquire and by default the npm modules are loaded even when stubbed. In my case I have a module called node-chartist that was being loaded during the first unit test and the others unit tests were using cache, I suppose. that is why the other unit tests weren't slower.

To solve this problem I had to use the method noCallThru() of proxyquire which make proxyquire don't load any original dependencies.

Kind regards